# Replacing Special Words in MySQL Using Script

Tags: mysql, database, special-characters, execute

I have a table that has lots of word with ID and Text. Some rows have special words. How can I filter them? I want it to be done in SQL (MySQL).

An example column is:

```
1 Blah/blah/blah
```

I need to make it `blah blah blah` or `blahblahblah`.

Is there anyone who can help me with script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql has a replace function that you can use:

```
REPLACE(column_name,char_to_replace,replacement_char)
```

so to turn blah/blah/blah to blah blah blah in your_column in some_table you would do this - you can always add a where clause to make it more specific:

```
UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET YOUR_COLUMN = REPLACE(your_column,"/"," ")
```

Comment: how i can apply this to whole table

Comment: You can just repeat this process for every column in the table. Does that not work? If for some reason your table has 1,000 columns you could write a script in your language of choice (php,python,etc) to automatically generate the necessary SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `REPLACE` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: how i can apply this to whole table